# How do I upgrade the version of Node.js on my Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

No matter what I do in my Terminal to upgrade Node.js it keeps showing me v13.12.0 and I'm not sure why.

Has anyone had this problem before? Is there a solution?

I even tried to downgrade to v12 and it seems to work, but then when I run "node -v" again it still shows v13.12.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Uninstall it, verfiy that its completly removed, install the new version. How did you installed it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed it ?
Using nvm or anything. If you use nvm just use this

```
  nvm install node_version // install the node's version
  nvm use node_version
  nvm alias default node_version
```

ps: node_version is something like `14.17`